What are the most unique and rare hydrangeas in the world?
I'm particularly interested in discovering exceptional, rare, or perhaps newly introduced hydrangea varieties. Could you share any recommendations or insights about hydrangeas that stand out due to their unusual colours, bloom shapes, or growth habits? Thank You so much!

your question is off topic here because it solicits opinions ... please take a tour of this site
